# error updating xamarin.google.ios.maps "Object reference not set to an instance of an object "

Tags: google-maps, xamarin.forms, xamarin.ios

I updated xamarin.google.ios.maps to 2.5.0 in the ios project, and i receive this error:

I receive this error after updating and compiling "Object reference not set to an instance of an object CmsMobile.iOS D:\Mis Proyectos\VS15\VC#\Xamarin\CmsMobile\packages\Xamarin.Build.Download.0.4.7\build\Xamarin.Build.Download.targets 52"

Take a look at this video https://1drv.ms/v/s!AtV6_4mjvBLeg-FWT61mxKMaWreDYQ

Thank you for your help

Comment: Try downgrade Xamarin.Build.Download from "0.4.7" to "0.4.5" and check if it helps or not.

Comment: Well it works because it downgrades xamarin.google.ios.maps to v2.1.0.2 automatically, not really what I want-

Comment: Delete the bin and obj folders, clean and try again.

Comment: @LandLu-MSFT Deleting the folders did not help :(